# reactive datatable linked to 2 action buttons not updating

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I am building a shiny app whose purpose is to generate an output dataset from an input dataset. The input dataset is subsetted interactively by the user which the app then displays statistical graphical output for those subgroups. From the statistical plots generated the user then determines some parameters for the subgroup and enters them into the output dataset with two action buttons. I haven't 1. been able to insert those parameters into the output table and 2. display the initialized output data at app startup.

Those two parameters are linked to separate action buttons. It made sense to me to assign the output table to two separate eventReactive calls for each button trigger. I think this is also why the app doesn't display the output table at the beginning as there is no action button trigger to initiate the table to render.

UI:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(DT)

dataIn = data.frame(list(grp1 = rnorm(20), grp2 = rnorm(20,5,3), grp3 = rnorm(20,5,.4) )) %>% gather(key = 'subgroup', value = 'value')
dataOut = data.frame(list(param1 = rep(0,3), param2 = rep(0,3)), row.names = c('x','y','z'))

ui = fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel('stats', fluid = FALSE,
  selectInput('subset','Subpopulation', choices = c('grp1', 'grp2', 'grp3')),
  numericInput('param1','Choose parameter 1', 1),
  actionButton('action1','Insert parameter 1'),
  numericInput('param2', 'Choose paramerter 2', 1),
  actionButton('action2', 'Insert parameter 2')
    ),
  tabPanel('table',fluid = FALSE,
    DT::dataTableOutput('table')
  ))
)
```

SERVER:

```
server = function(input, output, session){
  tableOut = reactive({dataOut})
  tableOut = eventReactive(input$action1,{
    dataOut[c('grp1','grp2','grp3') == input$subset, 1] <<- input$param1
    print(dataOut)
    dataOut})

  tableOut = eventReactive(input$action2,{
    dataOut[c('grp1','grp2','grp3') == input$subset, 2] <<- input$param2
    print(dataOut)
    dataOut
  })

  output$table = DT::renderDataTable(tableOut(), options = list(scrolly = TRUE, 
    length = 100))

  }
```

Again I would like for the output table to display upon startup. The table only displays after I hit the second action button. Also there is no update at all for `param1` upon clickin the first action button so it seems the first eventReactive is not seen. I would like for the two parameters to be inserted separately into the table but I  haven't been able to find any alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simplified example without the actionButtons. Your main issue is using reactive values. Please look at some documentation as you should not be using the global assignment operator <<- in a shiny app. There is room for improvement but this should work.

global & ui:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(DT)

dataIn = data.frame(list(grp1 = rnorm(20), grp2 = rnorm(20,5,3), grp3 = rnorm(20,5,.4) )) %>% gather(key = 'subgroup', value = 'value')
dataOut = data.frame(list(param1 = rep(0,3), param2 = rep(0,3)), row.names = c('x','y','z'))

ui = fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel('stats', fluid = FALSE,
  selectInput('subset','Subpopulation', choices = c('grp1', 'grp2', 'grp3')),
  numericInput('param1','Choose parameter 1', 1),
  numericInput('param2', 'Choose paramerter 2', 1)
    ),
  tabPanel('table',fluid = FALSE,
    DT::dataTableOutput('table')
  ))
)
```

server:

```
server = function(input, output, session){
    values = reactiveValues(tableOut = dataOut)
    tableOut = reactive({
        values$tableOut[c('grp1','grp2','grp3') == input$subset, 1] <- input$param1
        values$tableOut[c('grp1','grp2','grp3') == input$subset, 2] <- input$param2
        print(values$tableOut)
    })

    output$table = DT::renderDataTable(tableOut(), options = list(scrolly = TRUE, 
                                                                  length = 100))

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Update:**

ui:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(DT)

dataIn = data.frame(list(grp1 = rnorm(20), grp2 = rnorm(20,5,3), grp3 = rnorm(20,5,.4) )) %>% gather(key = 'subgroup', value = 'value')
dataOut = data.frame(list(param1 = rep(0,3), param2 = rep(0,3)), row.names = c('x','y','z'))

ui = fluidPage(
    tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel('stats', fluid = FALSE,
                 selectInput('subset','Subpopulation', choices = c('grp1', 'grp2', 'grp3')),
                 numericInput('param1','Choose parameter 1', 1),
                 actionButton('action1','Insert parameter 1'),
                 numericInput('param2', 'Choose paramerter 2', 1),
                 actionButton('action2', 'Insert parameter 2')
        ),
        tabPanel('table',fluid = FALSE,
                 DT::dataTableOutput('table')
        ))
)
```

server:

```
server = function(input, output, session){
    values = reactiveValues(tableOut = dataOut)
    observeEvent(input$action1,{
        values$tableOut[c('grp1','grp2','grp3') == input$subset, 1] <- input$param1
        print(values$tableOut)
    })

    observeEvent(input$action2,{
        values$tableOut[c('grp1','grp2','grp3') == input$subset, 2] <- input$param2
        print(values$tableOut)
    })


    output$table = DT::renderDataTable(values$tableOut, options = list(scrolly = TRUE, 
                                                                  length = 100))

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The improvement I mentioned is that this runs both lines values$tableOut[c('grp1','grp2','grp3') == input$subset, 1] <- input$param1    and
        values$tableOut[c('grp1','grp2','grp3') == input$subset, 2] <- input$param2  every time either changes. Although this doesn't affect the correctness of the result it is somewhat unnecessary.

Comment: That solution doesn't offer the desired functionality I am going for. I would really like to have 1. the two fields update independently and 2. not spontaneously whenever the input fields  are changed -- hence the action buttons and the need for an observe or event call.  I will play around with this suggestion though. Thank you

Comment: Please see updated answer based on your desired functionality. It uses observeEvents instead of eventReactives